# How to convert data row to custom model

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a custom model like this:

```
 public class VoteOptionModel
  {
    public List<int> Index { get; set; }
    public List<string> Description { get; set; }
  }
```

And i have a method returns me a datatable.I want to bind database values to my custom model.

```
 var filed1= dt.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<int>("field1")).ToList();
 var field2= dt.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string("field2")).ToList();
 VoteOptionModel model= new VoteOptionModel();
 model.Index = visindex;
 model.Description = description;
```

That code is ok but i'm wondering if there is a "better" way. Can we use `AsEnumarable()` method?

`dt.AsEnumarable().Select(r=>new VoteOptionModel{Index=r["filed1"].toList()});` or sth.

Comment: Why not have list of models instead of model with list of values?

Answer (score 1):

You can gather all aggregated data in one run (make sure you initialize lists in model constructor) with [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var model = dt.AsEnumerable().Aggregate(new VoteOptionModel(),
              (model,r) => {
                model.Index.Add(r.Field<int>("field1"));
                model.Description.Add(r.Field<string>("field2"));
                return model;
             });
```

If you don't want to change model's constructor, then initialize model this way:

```
new VoteOptionModel() { 
      Index = new List<int>(), 
      Description = new List<string>() 
}
```

But I would suggest to have list of models instead of aggregated model, thus you have pairs of index and description values which are strongly related to each other:

```
public class VoteOptionModel
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And getting them this way:

```
var models = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new VoteOptionModel {
                 Index = r.Field<int>("field1"),
                 Description = r.Field<string>("field2")
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think your missing some `)` at the end of Add methods.

Comment: @TI yep, thanks! Don't have Visual Studio running :)